# Synthesizing bitfile in project mode, only if inputs have changed

Tags: build, dependencies, fpga, xilinx, vivado

I'd like to run a full synthesis pipeline for my Vivado project, from a script, using "project mode". The reason I want to use project mode is to get the exact same state if I decide to open the given project in the Vivado GUI, for e.g. simulations.

The problem is that the build script either fails or always rebuilds everything. My script is stripped down to its essentials:

```
open_project BlinkenLights/BlinkenLights.xpr
update_compile_order -fileset sources_1
launch_runs synth_1
launch_runs impl_1 -to_step write_bitstream
wait_on_run impl_1
```

With this version, if I re-run this script (using `vivado -mode batch -source build.tcl`) after a successful build, I get the following error message:

> ```
> ERROR: [Common 17-69] Command failed:  
> Run 'synth_1' needs to be reset before launching. 
> The run can be reset using the Tcl command 'reset_run synth_1'.
> ```

But that's not what I want; if I add `reset_run synth_1` before the `launch_runs synth_1` line, it causes the build to always start from scratch, even if no source files have changed.

What I'd like instead is to SUCCEEDS without doing work if the bitstream is already up-to-date, instead of FAILING, since I'm integrating it into a larger build system.

Comment: There is a property of `runs` called `STATUS`. You could use it to check the status of the synthesized design and decide if you want to reset and launch or don't do anything at all. Example: `get_property STATUS [get_runs synth_1]`. It returns `synth_design Complete!` if the design has succeeded.